# .NET Get SP Item Value from Column of Multi-Line Type

Tags: c#, .net, list, sharepoint

I am unable to get the value of an `item` in `SPList` from it's column which is `multi-line` type. `single-line` type column has no errors.

**Error:**

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

```
foreach (SPListItem item in myList.Items)
{
    //column: single-line type
    string function = item["Function"].ToString();

    //column: multi-line type - error-ed
    string parameters = item["Parameters"].ToString();
}
```

---

**Columns:**

[image]

---

**Function column (single-line)**
[image]

---

**Parameters column (multi line)**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SPField.GetFieldValueAsText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms450326(v=office.14)) Method to get the field value as plain text.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp/sites/jerry"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        var list = web.Lists.TryGetList("TestList");
        var item = list.GetItemById(1);
        var eventDescField = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Parameters");
        var eventDesc = item[eventDescField.Id];
        var eventDescText = eventDescField.GetFieldValueAsText(eventDesc);

    }
}
```